# Files disappearing in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: hard-drive, nautilus

Intro: I have a WD My Passport Ultra hard drive. I unplugged the HDD from my computer, used it in someone else's and then returned to my machine. When I tried to access a folder, it was no longer there.

Symptoms:

- The folder still exists as well as its contents. If I open the Terminal and use `ls` the folder is listed.
- The folder is not simply hidden (with a dot in the name), and `Ctrl+h` does not work
- If I open Nautilus as root, the folder is shown normally.
- All other folders in the HDD are still notmal (as far as I noticed).
- I don't think it is an issue with the HDD because it happened some time ago with a flash drive.

Thank you for anyone who can solve or at least find out what is causing this issue.

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing that this is a permissions issue. Open a terminal, navigate to that drive, issue  `ls -al` and have a look at the owners and permissions. If the info for the problem directory is different than for the others then `chmod`, `chown` and `chgrp` will be your friends.